# Modular Exponentiation using Euler's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

How would one go about computing the following value:

$8^{223}$ mod 69

using Euler's Theorem:

$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod }m)$

I've found the factorization of 69 to be 23 and 3 and used this to find the phi function:

$\phi(69) = (23^{1} - 23^{0})(3^{1} - 3^{0}) = 44$

Using this, I can conclude the following:

$8^{44} \text{mod } 69 = 1$

But, I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done on this so far?

Comment: you aren't solving an equation, you're computing a value. Different thing altogether I think.

Comment: @saulspatz So I calculated the phi function of 69, which is 44, and found the prime factorization of 69, 23 x 3.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for clarifying. I’ve edited the question.

Comment: @user3525572 You should have put this information into the body of your question.  Then it probably would not have been put on hold.  Next time it might be placed on hold before you get an answer, so be sure to give context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler's theorem states that if $a$ and $m$ are co-prime; then $$a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\bmod m.$$

Since $8$ and $69$ are indeed co-prime; we have $\varphi(69)=\varphi(3)\varphi(23)=44,$ so $$8^{44}\equiv 1\mod 69.$$

Working in modulo $69$, we have
$$8^{220}=(8^{44})^5=1,$$ and so $$8^{223}=8^{220}\cdot8^3=8^3=29. $$